# create wall in android application

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I can perform as a native application on android that contains a wall as the Facebook application, I have communication with the webservice using a mysql database but basically what I want to know is how I should send that information to place in my wall of my Android app, do not like the design of the wall, if I need the help of listview, or something else, also not like painting the data string in that wall, please help me, to be displayed as well as the wall facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too open ended (and also a bit muddled). You can send down the data in whatever format you want (XML or JSON are the preferred ways). Of course you then need to read this data using some sort of serialization library (Jackson for JSON is a good one). Then you probably want to display the data in a ListView, creating a custom Adapter.

There are a lot of pieces to this kind of app, so you're better off building one feature at a time and asking questions about the specific problem you are having. I suggest you figure out how to get the data from the server into the phone first.

Comment: Thanks friend for your ayuda.se Interact with the webservice as JSON In This case, I could help wanted by faort Mostar in what is Perhaps the wall with a listview?, And hit all that information so That exit der pictures like facebook, some api to display on the wall? ...